# Adding a new DishdetailComponent to React application to displays the details of a Specific dish

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-state

I am new to React and I am facing a issue to get item details when an item is clicked in React from an another Dishdetail component. I have MenuComponent.js which is supposed to call the DishDetailComponent.js when any of the card is clicked, however I am getting no response, nothing happens on clicking.

Here is the code of Menu Component used to call the Dish detail Component:

```
import { div } from 'prelude-ls';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardBody, CardTitle, CardText, CardImgOverlay } from 'reactstrap';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';

//Adding a new component
class Menu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedDish: null,
        }

    }
    //By this we change the state
    onDishSelect(dish) {
        this.setState({ selectedDish: dish });
    }


    render() {
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <Card onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                        <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                        <CardImgOverlay>
                            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        </CardImgOverlay>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {menu}
                </div>
                {/* This will render the dish on which we have clicked  */}
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 ml-1">
                        <DishDetail />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Menu;
```

And Here is my DishdetailComponent :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardBody, CardTitle, CardText, CardImgOverlay } from 'reactstrap';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';


// Adding DishDetail component
class DishDetail extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dishes: DISHES,
        };
    }


    renderDish(dish) {
        if (dish != null) {
            return (
                <div key={dish.id} className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                        <Card>
                            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                            <CardBody>
                                <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                                <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div></div>
            )
        }
    }

    renderComments(comments) {
        if(comments==null){
            return(
                <div></div>
            )
        }
        const showComments = comments.map((cmnt) => {
            return(
                <li key={cmnt.id}>
                    <p>cmnt.comment</p>
                    <p>--cmnt.author,cmnt.date</p>
                </li>
            )
        });

        return(
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <h3>Comments</h3>
                {showComments}
            </div>
        )
    }


    render() {
        const dish = this.props.dish;
        if(dish == null)
        {
            return(
                <div></div>
            )
        }
        const dishItem = this.renderDish(dish);
        const dishComment = this.renderComments(dish.comments);
    
        <div className="container">
            {dishItem}
            {dishComment}
        </div>
    }
}



export default DishDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your onDishSelect function.

See below:

```
import { div } from 'prelude-ls';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardBody, CardTitle, CardText, CardImgOverlay } from 'reactstrap';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';

//Adding a new component
class Menu extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        selectedDish: null,
    }
    // BINDING YOUR FUNCTION
    this.onDishSelect = this.onDishSelect.bind(this);


}
//By this we change the state
onDishSelect(dish) {
    this.setState({ selectedDish: dish });
}


render() {
    const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
        return (
            <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <Card onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardImgOverlay>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                    </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    });
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                {menu}
            </div>
            {/* This will render the dish on which we have clicked  */}
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 ml-1">
                    <DishDetail />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default Menu;

This should fix your issue.
If you dont want to bind all your declared fuctions, then use ES6 syntax.

i.e define your onDishSelect function like this:

```
onDishSelect = () => {
this.setState({ selectedDish: dish });
}
```

Comment: It still not giving any response

Answer (score 0):

you haven't passed props to DishDetail component, it should be:

```
<DishDetail dish={this.state.selectedDish} />
```

and also do the implementations suggested by user: @Sankshit Pandoh

Answer (score 0):

I found the following error in the render() method of DishdetailComponent - the dishDetail object was not being returned if dish != null:

```
render() {
    const dish = this.props.dish;
    if(dish == null)
    {
        return(
            <div></div>
        )
    } else {
        const dishItem = this.renderDish(dish);
        const dishComment = this.renderComments(dish.comments);
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {dishItem}
                {dishComment}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```